# Configuration profile installation using safari and return to native application

Tags: ios

I have written a code that will install the configuration profile on the device with the help of safari. After the profile is installed properly i am not able to return back to the Native application. I have seen it is done by Onavo count application.

Comment: Possible duplicate .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512718/return-to-app-from-safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by handling a custom url scheme. Check out following article, hope it helps.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: I am able to do this individually. If a give custom URL schema in safari the native appication is opened. My problem is that i must download a custom configuration profile, after the installation of profile i have to go back to the application.

Comment: Could you please explain `custom configuration profile` and what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Configuration profile will install proxy settings to the device.